# Cannot open file Dinput.lib

Tags: c++, directx, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to update an old program to use a more up to date version of DirectX. When I build my application I get an error "Cannot open file Dinput.lib". I don't want to open Dinput.lib. How do I find where this is being referenced, I want to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the reference by unloading my project and editing the vcxproj file (via right-click edit) I found the reference in an AdditionalDependencies tag

Comment: it is not a good way to edit the vcxproj file in text mode because you can corrupt it structure and you will no longer be able to open your project. you can do this in : project -> properties-> link -> input

Comment: It's more about searching than editing, when you don't know where the reference is coming from.